# JS: Compare two tables and generate new one based on the two

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get better at JavaScript/jQuery, so I guess some basic table manipulation would nice to try out. However I can't seem to find a way to get started doing what I want to achieve.

Lets say e.g. I have two tables, and I want to compare data and generate a third table based on the data in the two first ones. Lets say it's about movies, and I have this list of users, and list of movies with a column of whom likes the movie. In the third on the fly generated table I want to collect these data and write out the movie with whom likes it.

```
users
<table id="table_1">
    <tr>
        <th>user ID</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>country</th>
    </tr>

    <tr><td>1</td>
        <td>martin</td>a
        <td>usa</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td>2</td>
        <td>james</td>
        <td>france</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
movies
<table id="table_2">
    <tr>
        <th>movie id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>users favorite (id)</th>
    </tr>

    <tr><td>2</td>
        <td>the expendables</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td>2</td>
        <td>titanic</td>
        <td>2, 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>

results

<div id="table">

</div>
```

I have this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fpeh6fna/

Comment: Is the data hard coded like the fiddle or coming from a database? Hard coded you would parse the html, then compare the parsed information. From a db, more likely, would be far more simple.

Comment: Yeah, it's hardcoded for now, since I'm just learning. I assume I'd have to treverse a lot in the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery each commands here, for example (just a section of the code you would want):

```
$('#table_1').children('tr').each(function() {
    var row = [];

    $(this).children('td').each(function() {
        row.push($(this).text());
    });

    rows.push(row);
});
```